# Suppose X is uniform on [0,1] and Y is N(0,1). If X and Y are independent find P(X< Y)

Tags: probability

Suppose X is uniform on [0,1] and Y is N(0,1). If X and Y are independent find P(X< Y)

Me and a friend have very different solutions. She got an integral that's not calculable, but I got.
$F_X(x)=\frac{x}1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and 1 for $x\ge1$
$f_y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}2}$
Then I found online $P(X<Y)=\int F_X(y)F_y(y)dy$
So
$$\int_0^1 \frac{y}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{y^2}2}+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}2}dy=\frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}2}}{\sqrt 2 * \sqrt\pi}+[1-\phi(1)]$$

Anyone see anything wrong? I don't know if my phi function is right but everything else seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluation of the first integral is wrong . The value of this term is $(1-\frac  1  {e^{1/2}}) \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}$.

Comment: what about the 2nd one?

Comment: The second one is correct.  The answer is $(1-\frac  1  {e^{1/2}}) \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}+\frac{1}{2}erfc(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = (1-\frac  1  {e^{1/2}}) \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} + (1-\Phi{(1)})$